# Entity Framework:Eager loading vs virtual loading in updating a many to many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many, lazy-loading, eager-loading

Eager loading is to load the specific navigation data.
Lazy loading is to load all related entities without using Include() method. 
I quite understand the concept.

But here I met a problem when I want to update a many to many relationship ( Students and Courses).

## Problem description:

**When I edit a student, I want to edit the selected courses as well. 
The problem is that when I use the eager loading , all works good. But for the lazy loading , there is an exception like "iolation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.StudentsCourses'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.StudentsCourses'. The duplicate key value is (1049, 3).
The statement has been terminated."**

### CustomersCourses Table:

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.CustomersCourses",
            c => new
                {
                    CustomerId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    CourseId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.CustomerId, t.CourseId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Customers", t => t.CustomerId, cascadeDelete: true )
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Courses", t => t.CourseId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.CustomerId)
            .Index(t => t.CourseId);
```

### Rename Customer Model to Student Model and  rename dbo.StudentCourse to  dbo.StudentsCourses accordingly

```
public override void Up()
    {
        RenameTable(name: "dbo.Customers", newName: "Students");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.CustomersCourses", "CustomerId", "dbo.Customers");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.CustomersCourses", "CourseId", "dbo.Courses");
        DropIndex("dbo.CustomersCourses", new[] { "CustomerId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.CustomersCourses", new[] { "CourseId" });
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.StudentsCourses",
            c => new
                {
                    StudentId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    CourseId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.StudentId, t.CourseId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Students", t => t.StudentId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Courses", t => t.CourseId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.StudentId)
            .Index(t => t.CourseId);

        //keep previous data from CustomersCourses Table before dropping 
        Sql("INSERT INTO StudentsCourses (StudentId,CourseId) SELECT CustomerId,CourseId FROM CustomersCourses");

        DropTable("dbo.CustomersCourses");
    }
```

### Eager loading  Student Model :

```
public class Student
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Range(16, 58)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    public IList<Course> CoursesEnrolled { get; set; }


    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public enum Gender
{
    Male,
    Femal,
    Others
}
```

### Course Model

```
public class Course
{
    public int  Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)] 
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

### Eager loading Edit function in StudentController

**use include extension method here**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
        var studentInDb = _context.Students.Include(s => s.CoursesEnrolled).SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
        if (studentInDb == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        StudnetFormViewModel studnetFormViewModel = new StudnetFormViewModel()
        {
            Student = studentInDb,
            Courses = _context.Courses.ToList()
        };
        return View("StudentForm", studnetFormViewModel);
}
```

### Eager loading Save function in StudentController

**use include extension method when load the SelectedCourses**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Student student)
{
        if (student.Id == 0)
        {
            Student studentInDb = new Student()
            {
                Name = student.Name,
                City = student.City,
                Age = student.Age,
                Gender = student.Gender,
            };
            var courseList = new List<Course>();
            foreach (var courseSelect in student.CoursesEnrolled)
            {
                var courseInDb = _context.Courses.SingleOrDefault(course => course.Id == courseSelect.Id);
                courseList.Add(courseInDb);
            }
            studentInDb.CoursesEnrolled = courseList;

            _context.Students.Add(studentInDb);

        }
        else
        {
            var studentInDb = _context.Students.Include(s => s.CoursesEnrolled).SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == student.Id);
            if (studentInDb == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            studentInDb.Name = student.Name;
            studentInDb.Age = student.Age;
            studentInDb.City = student.City;
            studentInDb.Gender = student.Gender;

            var courseList = new List<Course>();
            if (student.CoursesEnrolled != null)
            {
                foreach (var courseSelect in student.CoursesEnrolled)
                {
                    var courseInDb = _context.Courses.SingleOrDefault(course => course.Id == courseSelect.Id);
                    courseList.Add(courseInDb);
                }
            }
            studentInDb.CoursesEnrolled = courseList;

            //                studentInDb.CoursesEnrolled = student.CoursesEnrolled;
            //                foreach (var course in studentInDb.CoursesEnrolled)
            //                {
            //                    _context.Entry(course).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            //                }
            //                _context.Students.Add(studentInDb);
            //                _context.Courses.Attach(studentInDb.CoursesEnrolled);
        }

        try
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            Exception raise = dbEx;
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
               foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                }
            }
            throw raise;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Student");

}
```

### Edit Studnet Page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Myxdc.png)

In this scenario, I can delete and add courses for students successfully. When I use the lazy loading.

### Lazy loading: Student Model

**describe  CoursesEnrolled  with virtual keyword.**

```
public class Student
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Range(16, 58)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Course> CoursesEnrolled { get; set; }


    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

### Lazy loading : Edit function in StudentController

just delete include method when I load the studentInDb.

```
var studentInDb = _context.Students.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
```

### Lazy loading : Save method in StudnetController

same to Save method

```
var studentInDb = _context.Students.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == student.Id);
```

When I try to save the changes of a student, here comes to the problem. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qNtw.png)

**I use the fidddler to get the detail. It shows : 'iolation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.StudentsCourses'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.StudentsCourses'. The duplicate key value is (1048, 3).
The statement has been terminated'**

### Quetions

#### 1.Why this problem happens in lazy loading ?

#### 2.How to fix this problem in lazy loading ?

## Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Does anyone have any idea about this issue?